# Golang func - return type

Tags: go

This is my first `Golang` program after 'Hello world'. Please find following code block which aims to perform basic arithmetic and multiple type return demo. This is just a hypothetical sample to learn `Go func`. However, I am getting following exception on compilation. From exception, i assume, operations on `int8` operand return `int16/int32` as return type and which is not correct as per go.

**Question:** Isn't it safe for language to assume `int8` is safely assignable to `int16` or `int32`

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func Arithmetic(a,b int8) (int8,string,int16,int32){
    return a-b, "add",a*b,a/b
}
func main() {
    a,b,c,d :=Arithmetic(5,10)
    fmt.Println(a,b,c,d)
}
```

**Error:**

```
C:/Go\bin\go.exe run C:/GoWorkspace/src/tlesource/ff.go
# command-line-arguments
.\ff.go:15: cannot use a * b (type int8) as type int16 in return argument
.\ff.go:15: cannot use a / b (type int8) as type int32 in return argument

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: You can't assign `int8` to `int16` or `int32`, but you can safely convert them.

Comment: You have to explicitly cast it using `int16()`, etc

Comment: @JimB, Thank you for your comment. I might be wrong, however, Safe assignment and conversion is different.

Comment: @ShmulikKlein, Thanks for your comment. Casting might be a valid if we try to down cast. But this is a case of up casting. So, I assume, this should be an easy task for compiler with out any helping hands.

Comment: @Nair: What exactly are you asking? You cannot assign an `int8` to an `int16`/`int32`/etc. Just because it's "safe" doesn't mean they are assignable; they are different types. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability

Comment: @JimB, Is it true that int8/int16/int32 are integer/integral type with varying storage capacity.

Comment: @Nair that's correct, int8/int16/int32 are 8 bits, 16 bits, and 32 bits wide as you'd expect. You may find https://tour.golang.org/basics/13 useful. You are also correct that the compiler *could* easily widen the smaller types to match the return types, but it doesn't. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should, and in this case it is the go philosophy that you should be explicit about such things; this satisfies the principle of least suprise.

Comment: I'm not sure some of us are obsessed with down voting without explaining what they found in question as off topic.

Comment: @SamWhited, If this is how Go designed to handle such situation then I accept it and I am open enough to respect every language it it's level. You can post you comment as answer in answer section.

Comment: @Nair: the question is probably downvoted because "Is it it safe for language to assume int8 is safely assignable to int16 or int32" is very unclear, which is one of the criteria for downvoting (and the number of comments here is an indication that many didn't understand what you're asking). The fact that it may theoretically be safe for "language" (Go?) to assign an `int8` to an `int16` is irrelevant, because the language as specified doesn't allow assignment between different underlying types (see "Assignability" specification link in my previous comment).

Comment: @JimB, Thank you for your guidance. I must go with Go and its strict type restriction to know why such assignability is not possible. Sorry still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it it safe for language to assume int8 is safely assignable to int16 or int32

Yes, It would be, if Go did implicit conversions on assignment. But it does not (only interface-wrapping when applicable).

There are several reasons:

- The concept of automatic conversion cannot be generalized to all types without introducing the concept of a type hierarchy. And, as you know, all concrete types in Go are invariant.
- Go is "anti-magic" and in this spirit it doesn't do stuff you did not request it to do (except e.g. write-barriers on pointers).

Answer (score 2):

The error says that you have to return **int16** and **int32**, all you have to do is convert the result like this:

```
func Arithmetic(a, b int8) (int8, string, int16, int32) {
    return a - b, "add", int16(a * b), int32(a / b)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. My Question was not how to fix error message. Rather, I am interested in knowing why Go can't make safe conversion

Comment: @Nair Why unable to do safe conversion? "Because that is how the language is defined".

Comment: You're probably better off doing `int16(a) * int16(b)` rather than `int16(a * b)`... Unless you can guarantee that `a *  b` won't wrap, that is.